# variable creation inside classes

Tags: php, variables

I am following a tutorial on dependency injection. My issue is that I do not understand how some of the variables are being formulated within the classes. Within class Author we have $firstname and $lastname. Within class Question we have $author and $question. Then magically(?) we have within the class Question constructor we get $authorFirstname and $authorLastname.

I don't get it - it's like they have been concatenated, but that can't be, right ?? But then the  $authorFirstname and $authorLastname have not been declared within class Question.

So, Question: how does the author get to the $authorFirstname and $authorLastname - or am I over thinking this ??

```
class Author {
    private $firstName;
    private $lastName;

    public function __construct($firstName, $lastName) {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;
        $this->lastName = $lastName;
    }

    public function getFirstName() {
        return $this->firstName;
    }

    public function getLastName() {
        return $this->lastName;
    }
}

class Question {
    private $author;
    private $question;

    public function __construct($question, $authorFirstName, $authorLastName) {
        $this->author = new Author($authorFirstName, $authorLastName);
        $this->question = $question;
    }

    public function getAuthor() {
        return $this->author;
    }

    public function getQuestion() {
        return $this->question;
    }
}
```

Comment: When defining a function/method, the arguments defined are the variable names that will be used for arguments inside the function/method; when calling a function/method, the arguments are in scope variable names whose values will be passed to the called function/method.... those names don't need to be identical

Comment: In your Question construct, the arguments you put in only exist inside the construct. You can see a new Author being created, where $authorFirst and $authorLast are used.

Comment: Just look one line up. There you find the definition of those. It's in the functions parameters. May I suggest over-reading the section about function parameters in the PHP manual? Also please keep personal tutoring requests to the venue of that tutorial. Contact the tutorial author for your support options. -  http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

Comment: Thank you for your response. I would prefer not to limit myself to the venue of the tutorial. Often tutorials are no longer monitored by the authors. Additionally it should be irrelevant where I get the supporting code from - the question is the focus of the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overthinking.

you notice, `__construct($question, $authorFirstName, $authorLastName)`...
construct is a special function that runs when a new object of that class is created.

`$authorFirstName` and `$authorLastName` are just variables to be passed to the Question constructor function, aka

```
$question = new Question($questioninfo,'William','Shakespeare');
```

(in this case, `$authorFirstName` = William, `$authorLastName` = Shakespeare)
They only get used within the scope of the `__construct()` function, which in this case instantiates a new Author. so if the input was as above, this will happen inside the constructor of Question:

```
$this->author = new Author('William', 'Shakespeare');
```

and those variables will be handled by Author's constructor, as `$firstName` and `$lastName`... make sense?

Answer (score 1):

The **Question** ctor is an example of a *hidden dependency*, ***not*** showing how dependency injection works:

```
public function __construct($question, $authorFirstName, $authorLastName) {
    $this->author = new Author($authorFirstName, $authorLastName);
    $this->question = $question;
}
```

As this code shows, the parameters `$authorFirstName`, `$authorLastName` are used to create the **Author** dependcy *inside* **Question**. Therefore the dependency is *not* injected.

Instead, the author should be injected:

```
public function __construct($question, Author $author) {
    $this->author   = $author;
    $this->question = $question;
}
```

The **Question** is only interested in compositing an **Author**, there is no need that the **Question** needs to create an **Author**.

I hope this also illustrates how parameters work.